# autorisation required for share file in google drive

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

With Google Drive for VB.Net, I managed to get a shareable link with another person, but when the person tries to open the file or put the link into the address bar, an error occurs "**Authorization required**".

Here is my code:

```
      Dim list = Service.Files.List()
    Dim count = list.Execute()
    For Each fich In count.Items
        If (fich.Title) = fichier Then

            fich.Shared = True
            Dim userpermit = New Permission()
            userpermit.Type = "user"
            userpermit.Role = "Reader"
            userpermit.Value = "*********"
            userpermit.EmailAddress = "*******"

            userpermit.WithLink = True
            listfile.adr_mail.Text = fich.AlternateLink ' to Get a shareable link 

            Dim req = Service.Permissions.Insert(userpermit, fich.Id)

            req.Fields = "id"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the reasons why the user aside from the owner cannot directly access the file even if there is a shareable link,

- The file may be private (for the owner only)
- The user trying to open the file may not be in the list of authorized user

To check the list of the users, use the [Try it now](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list#try-it) part.

You need to supply the `fileId`.

[image]

> ```
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/permissions
> ```

and you will get response like this:

```
 {
   "kind": "",
   "etag": "",
   "id": "",
   "selfLink": "",
   "name": "",
   "emailAddress": "@something.com",
   "domain": "something.com",
   "role": "owner",
   "type": "user",
   "deleted":
  }
```

Comment: I forget .execute () in insert permission and i change Reader to reader ..and it's work